# SQL function in stored procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure I try to use a function.

Code below:

```
SELECT TOP 4 
    refFeatured,
    [Type],
    [Order],
    fn_cms_featured_image(refFeatured,[Type],@refLanguage) AS FeaturedImage,
    fn_cms_featured_name(refFeatured,[Type],@refLanguage) AS Name 
FROM
    FEATURED
ORDER BY 
    [Order] ASC
```

I wrote function but not working.

> 'fn_cms_featured_image' is not a recognized function name.

the above error occurs. Where do I make mistake.

functions are scalar-valued functions.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_cms_featured_image] ( @iNumber int,@type nvarchar(20),@lang int )
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @image  nvarchar(100)

    IF @type ='Category'
        SET @image = (SELECT TOP 1 c.Icon FROM CATEGORY c WHERE c.Id=@iNumber)
    ELSE
        SET @image = (SELECT TOP 1 pl.DefaultImage FROM  PRODUCT_IMAGE_LOCALIZED pl WHERE  pl.refLanguage=@lang AND pl.refProduct=@iNumber)

    RETURN (@image)
END
```

Comment: I'd also advice not to use scalar functions in your code, they're performance bottlenecks, rewrite them using inline table valued functions.

Comment: Is your problem solved by any one of the answer or still the problem exist?

Answer (score 2):

Add schema name `[dbo].` in front of the function name.

```
SELECT TOP 4 refFeatured, 
       [Type],
       [Order], 
       [dbo].fn_cms_featured_image(refFeatured,[Type],@refLanguage) AS FeaturedImage, 
       [dbo].fn_cms_featured_name(refFeatured,[Type],@refLanguage) AS Name 
FROM  FEATURED 
ORDER BY [Order] ASC
```

Have a look on this post: [Why is the schema prefix (dbo) mandatory when we call a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/142984/)

Answer (score 1):

Name of user function should be called preceded by schema name.
Try writing `SELECT dbo.fn_cms_featured_image(...`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select item from fn_cms_featured_image(refFeatured,[Type],@refLanguage) AS FeaturedImage
```

instead of direct call

```
fn_cms_featured_image(refFeatured,[Type],@refLanguage) AS FeaturedImage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- While selecting function name IN select query always select dbo.function name.      
SELECT TOP 4 
    refFeatured, [Type], [Order],
    dbo.fn_cms_featured_image(refFeatured,[Type], @refLanguage) AS FeaturedImage,
    dbo.fn_cms_featured_name(refFeatured, [Type], @refLanguage) AS Name 
FROM  
    FEATURED 
ORDER BY 
    [Order] ASC
```